# Deactivate Azure File Sync

Tags: azure, azure-files, azure-file-copy

Here in My work, we have Azure File Sync in our file server and works great.  But now we need to cancel that service and use a private cloud to store our files.

How to make all files in My server available to copy to another location?  We try to shutdown the subscription before, and a lot of files became unavailable to copy on server.

BR.

Answer (score 0):

AzCopy is a command-line utility that you can use to copy files to or from a storage account. This article contains example commands that work with Azure Files.
You can you azcopy tool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-files

Additional information: You may also refer to Azure Data Factory([Copy data from or to Azure Files by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-file-storage?tabs=data-factory))